# How do I print file new from the loop using fwrite in R?

Tags: r

my code bellow is printing me a file EQTLs.txt which looks like this:

```
1_949654_A_G_b37 1 949654
1_1212649_T_C_b37 1 1212649
...

library(data.table)

fileNames <- fread("genes_103", header=F)
s=fread("snpPos", header=TRUE)


for (fileName in noquote(fileNames$V1)) {

 if (file.exists(fileName))

  # read original data:
  e <- fread(fileName, header = FALSE,sep = ",",skip=3)

  EQTLs<-s[s$POS==as.numeric(e[tail(which(e$V2 == min(e$V2)), 1),1]),]
#V2 is obs_pval

  # write new data to separate file:
    fwrite(EQTLs,
    "EQTLs.txt",
    append = TRUE,
    sep = " ",
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE)
}
```

I would like in addition for this fwrite function to output the names of my files in variable fileName.

My fileName would look like this: ENSG00000163995.14.CovRE.pval.txt

So one line of the output of EQTLs.txt would ideally look like this:

```
ENSG00000163995.14.CovRE.pval.txt     1_949654_A_G_b37 1 949654
ENSG00000219665.4.CovRE.pval.txt      1_1212649_T_C_b37 1 1212649
    ...
```

How to achieve this with this fwrite function?

Thanks

Comment: how about `EQTLs$filename <- fileName`

Comment: where do I put that in fwrite function and how?

Comment: I need to put somehow variable fileName from the loop in fwrite function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the filename to the `EQTLs` object before writing to the file

```
for (fileName in noquote(fileNames$V1)) {

 if (file.exists(fileName))

  # read original data:
  e <- fread(fileName, header = FALSE,sep = ",",skip=3)

  EQTLs<-s[s$POS==as.numeric(e[tail(which(e$V2 == min(e$V2)), 1),1]),]  #V2 is obs_pval
  EQTLs$filename <- fileName #this will add the file name to EQTLs

  # write new data to separate file:
    fwrite(EQTLs[, c(4,1,2,3)],
    "EQTLs.txt",
    append = TRUE,
    sep = " ",
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE)
}
```